# Referencing outer variables for main method c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I would like to know how to reference outer variables in the main method. I have managed to do some and it compiles but I can't seem to do **"static string ticket"** & **"static char seat"**. This is my code so far:

```
public class Cinema
{
    static int[,] cinema;
    static char[,] cinchar;
    static string ticket;
    static int[] row;
    static char seat;

    //--------------------------------
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cinema = new int[10, 5];
        cinchar = new char[10, 5];
        //I want to reference the above **static string ticket** variable here
        row = new int[3];
        //I want to reference the above **static char seat** variable here

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                cinchar[i, j] = (char)'*';
                cinema[i, j] = 0;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I want to reference the outer variables "static string ticket" & "static char seat" in the main method. As I have done with the other ones.

Comment: @Heath so what exactly is not working for you ? Define what *reference* means to you ...

Comment: Everything works, however in order to make my console appear i need *static string ticket;* & *static char seat;* to be mentioned in the main method.

Comment: Try `Console.ReadLine();` before the `}` of the `Main` method

Comment: ticket = "whatever you want"; seat = 's'; both work. Can you be more specific what does not work for you. For example the error message you get?

Comment: @Heath: No, you don't.  They're already in scope.

Comment: @Eiver there is no error message, my problem is i'm getting a blank console window because static string ticket; & static char seat; are not mentioned in the main method. E.g. i mentioned static int[] row; outside the main method and included it inside by writing row = new int[3]. How would i go about doing it the same for the remaining two?

Comment: Try `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");` to print something in the console.

Comment: [Getting started with C# Language: Console Application](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/15/getting-started-with-c-sharp-language/26/creating-a-new-console-application-visual-studio#t=20161107230550839105)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Cinema
{
    static int[,] cinema;
    static char[,] cinchar;
    static string ticket;
    static int[] row;
    static char seat;

    //--------------------------------
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cinema = new int[10, 5];
        cinchar = new char[10, 5];
        ticket = "new ticket";
        //I want to reference the above **static string ticket** variable here
        row = new int[3];
        seat = 'a';
        Console.WriteLine("Ticket: " + ticket + ", Seat: " + seat.ToString());
        //I want to reference the above **static char seat** variable here

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                cinchar[i, j] = (char)'*';
                cinema[i, j] = 0;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produces
Ticket: new ticket, Seat: a